# How could I get the top X records per distinct column within each range of Y timestamp, for some other column Z?

Tags: mysql

So far, I'm using a lot of small queries in a loop to achieve this.  I'm hoping there is a way to concentrate this into a single query since these queries are starting to take hours to finish (millions of rows), with some expected tests requiring twenty times that amount of data.
Is there a way to write a query that gets X number of records of distinct device_id (a column) for each time step Y for test_id Z?

With some example data:

```
| ts                  | test_id | device_id | data     |
| 2018-06-25 06:00:00 | 0       | 1         | "blah00" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:00 | 1       | 1         | "blah01" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:00 | 1       | 2         | "blah02" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:02 | 1       | 1         | "blah03" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:02 | 1       | 2         | "blah04" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:05 | 1       | 1         | "blah05" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:05 | 1       | 2         | "blah06" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:08 | 1       | 1         | "blah07" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:08 | 1       | 2         | "blah08" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:10 | 1       | 1         | "blah09" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:10 | 1       | 2         | "blah10" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:12 | 1       | 1         | "blah11" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:12 | 1       | 2         | "blah12" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:15 | 1       | 1         | "blah13" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:18 | 1       | 1         | "blah14" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:20 | 1       | 1         | "blah15" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:20 | 1       | 2         | "blah16" |
```

And I wanted the top 3 records for every 10 seconds for test_id 1, I'd like to get the result:

```
| ts                  | test_id | device_id | data     |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:00 | 1       | 1         | "blah01" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:00 | 1       | 2         | "blah02" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:02 | 1       | 1         | "blah03" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:02 | 1       | 2         | "blah04" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:05 | 1       | 1         | "blah05" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:05 | 1       | 2         | "blah06" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:10 | 1       | 1         | "blah09" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:10 | 1       | 2         | "blah10" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:12 | 1       | 1         | "blah11" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:12 | 1       | 2         | "blah12" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:15 | 1       | 1         | "blah13" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:20 | 1       | 1         | "blah15" |
| 2018-06-25 08:00:20 | 1       | 2         | "blah16" |
```

A few things that can't be taken for granted is that a device might fail to record for some time (thus I can't guarantee each device would have the same number of rows per time frame (as I attempted to replicate in the sample data) including having all of the devices paused for some time (thus it could be possible for to have no data for one or more consecutive time frames).

My current queries (and surrounding pseudo-code) are - angle brackets indicate some value that would be set to the applicable value:

```
For each distinct device_id in test_id Z


SELECT ts FROM data_log
WHERE (test_id=<Z> AND device_id=<device_id>)
ORDER BY ts 
LIMIT 1

Store as newest

SELECT ts FROM data_log
WHERE (test_id=<Z> AND device_id=<device_id>)
ORDER BY ts 
LIMIT 1

Store as oldest

For currentTime = newest; currentTime < oldest; currentTime += timestep Y

SELECT * FROM data_log
WHERE (test_id=<Z> AND device_id=<device_id> AND ts>=<currentTime>)
ORDER BY ts
LIMIT <X>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have a key on on (test_id, ts) - columns in that order, important. Then you can do

`select * from t where test_id = 1 order by ts`

and process the output on the client filtering out the records you do not want. This should give you an OK though not stellar performance if you have under 10 M records for each test id.

If you are good with C++, and you want to get better performance, you can write a [UDF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html). There are some tricks you will need to do for this one. Use `initid->ptr` allocating memory to use it for your buffer to keep state. Then in that memory area you can remember the info about the rows previously seen which will allow you to decide if you should or should not include the current row in the result. Your query then will be something like this:

`select * from t where test_id = 1 and should_include_test(ts,device_id) order by ts`

Comment: But client side filtering is exactly what I'm attempting to avoid.  Also, there is a Primary Key, I felt it was noise for the example data.

Comment: Post your exact queries and key layout. My suspicion at this point is that client side filtering is not what is killing you, but rather a large amount of queries without a key. This problem can potentially be solved without client side filtering, but it would require some work - see my UDF solution outline. However, I believe you can achieve decent performance with client side filtering if you had proper keys in the table. Keys are critical. Do not fall for the trap that if you just have some key the query will be fast. The key needs to be tailored for the query.